# A problem in linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $x,y\in\Bbb Q^n$ and $A\in\Bbb Q^{n\times n}$ how do you find $k\in\Bbb N_{>1}$ such that $x'A^ky=1$ assuming $x'y=1$?

Is there an elementary procedure?

Comment: The equation may be solutionless, depending on $\;x,y,A\;$,  and even asserting this seems to be hopeless in the general case

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, there may be no solution. But, if there is any, finding eigenvalues of $A$ would help. If you could write $A$ as $PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is a block diagonal matrix, then $A^k$ would be \begin{aligned}A^k&=(PDP^{-1})^k\\&=\underbrace{PDP^{-1}PDP^{-1}\cdots PDP^{-1}}_{k\,\mathrm{times}} \\&=PD(P^{-1}P)D(P^{-1}P)\cdots (P^{-1}P)DP^{-1}\\
&=PD^kP^{-1}\end{aligned}
And since $D$ is block diagonal it's easier to deal with $D^k$. Also note that \begin{aligned}1&=x'A^ky\\&=x'PD^kP^{-1}y\\&=(x'P)D^k(P^{-1}y)\end{aligned}
By defining new vectors $u=P'x$ and $v=P^{-1}y$, you'll get to solve the easier equation $$1=u'D^kv$$ for $k$. Moreover, $u'v=1$ because $$u'v=x'PP^{-1}y=x'y=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Just as @DonAntonio said, it may be solutionless.  Here is an example.
Let $A=rI$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $r >1$. Now
$$x'A^ky=x'(rI)^ky=x'(r^kI^k)y=r^k(x'I^ky)=r^kx'y=r^k$$
Note that for any $k>1$, it must have
$$x'A^ky=r^k>1.$$